# react native Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call

Tags: react-native, hook

I am trying to use this module from react-native-toast-banner, the code you see below was functioning perfectly earlier during the day, and somehow it is not anymore, and for the life of me i can't figure out what i have changed that broke it.

```
import {
  ToastBannerProvider,
  ToastBannerPresenter,
  useToastBannerToggler /* or withToastBannerToggler */,
  Transition,
} from "react-native-toast-banner";


const Notibanner = (type, message) => {
  
const { showBanner, hideBanner } = useToastBannerToggler();
return  showBanner({
    contentView: (
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor:
            type === "success"
              ? "green"
              : type === "warning"
              ? "orange"
              : type === "danger"
              ? "red"
              : "lightblue",
          margin: 20,
          padding: 5,
          borderRadius: 5,
          flexDirection: "row",
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            marginHorizontal: 5,
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
          }}
          source={
            type === "success"
              ? require("./../../images/success.png")
              : type === "warning"
              ? require("./../../images/warning.png")
              : type === "danger"
              ? require("./../../images/danger.png")
              : require("./../../images/info.png")
          }
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "white",
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            marginHorizontal: 20,
          }}
        >
          {message}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ),
    duration: 3000 /* default: 3000 */,
    transitions: [Transition.Move],
    disableHideOnPress: false,
  });
};
```

and i call that function by :

```
        <Button
          containerStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}
          buttonStyle={styles.submitButton}
          loading={auth.loggingIn}
          onPress={() => {
            oldpassword === "" || password === "" || confirmpassword === ""
            ? Notibanner("warning", "complete all fields!")
            : password !== confirmpassword 
            ? Notibanner("warning", "password not matching")
            : sendData();
          }}
          title="update"
        />
```

I even tried going back to the original example code but i get the same error:

Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call

the full error log is visible in this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kRXe.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't return a hook like `showBanner`

move your code to where you have your `Button`, then remove the `return` in your Notibanner function.

```
import {
  ToastBannerProvider,
  ToastBannerPresenter,
  useToastBannerToggler /* or withToastBannerToggler */,
  Transition,
} from "react-native-toast-banner";

const { showBanner, hideBanner } = useToastBannerToggler();

const Notibanner = (type, message) => {
   showBanner({
    contentView: (
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor:
            type === "success"
              ? "green"
              : type === "warning"
              ? "orange"
              : type === "danger"
              ? "red"
              : "lightblue",
          margin: 20,
          padding: 5,
          borderRadius: 5,
          flexDirection: "row",
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            marginHorizontal: 5,
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
          }}
          source={
            type === "success"
              ? require("./../../images/success.png")
              : type === "warning"
              ? require("./../../images/warning.png")
              : type === "danger"
              ? require("./../../images/danger.png")
              : require("./../../images/info.png")
          }
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "white",
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            marginHorizontal: 20,
          }}
        >
          {message}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ),
    duration: 3000 /* default: 3000 */,
    transitions: [Transition.Move],
    disableHideOnPress: false,
  });
```

};

Comment: This works, yet i have no idea why or how, i'll take some time to study that, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can just make it a custom hooks
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!